# React Native: How do payments among users in mobile marketplace app work?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, stripe-payments

I would like to have users within a React Native mobile app where users can post up items and other users can purchase them.

My question is, what would be the best approach to this? More specifically, how can I get a user to send a payment directly to another user? Or does the platform become the middle-man, where it receives the payment from the buyer and the platform sends the payment to the seller?

I have looked into Stripe but I am only seeing how to charge a user directly and the user would make the payment out to me (the platform), but I would like where the user would make a payment directly to another user, preferably through Stripe or any other better methods out there.

Thank you in advance. I will accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: unless you use bitcoin I doubt you can legally handle money transfers between users, look into venmo or paypal

Comment: @Davidlrnt is correct.  You cannot transfer money between users on the Stripe platform unless the money is associated with a third-party transaction.  (eg. customer is paying you, and another user gets a portion of the costs.)

Comment: @Davidlrnt So is that how marketplace mobile apps like 5Miles (https://www.5milesapp.com/) are handled, via Venmo or PayPal?

Comment: @korben So my question is what would be a good method to go with for handling money exchange between users in market place mobile app?

Answer (score 2):

Stripe recently launched Stripe Connect to facilitate marketplace payment: https://stripe.com/connect